# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "

Tags: java, swing, integer, actionlistener, jtextfield

I know there are a lot of topic like this but i can't find where is my mistake because i think i did everything okay. Simply, i want to do is creat a gui, it will want a number from me lets say it's "x" and if x<50 it will say "Geçtin" else "Kaldın" but it looks i cant set anything on "Text". 
Thats my cods,

## Guibaslatma.java

public class Guibaslatma {

```
    public static void main(String[]args) {
    gui a = new gui();
    a.guii();






    }
}
```

## Gui.java

```
 import javax.swing.*;  

public class gui extends JFrame {

    JButton tıkla = new JButton("Tıkla beni");
    JTextField Text = new JTextField();

  public  void guii() {

      this.setTitle("Ahmet");
      this.setLayout(null);
      this.setSize(1000,1000);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setVisible(true);

      Text.setSize(200,50);
      Text.setLocation(250,250);
      Text.setVisible(true);
      Text.setVisible(true);

      this.getContentPane().add(Text);


      tıkla.addActionListener(new Action());
      tıkla.setSize(100,100);
      tıkla.setLocation(250,350);
      tıkla.setVisible(true);
      this.getContentPane().add(tıkla);

      String getText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Bir sayı gir");
      Text.setText(getText);
    }
}
```

## Action.java# `import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Action implements ActionListener {

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    gui b = new gui();

    int a = Integer.parseInt(b.Text.getText());
    if(a< 50) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kaldın", "Mesaj -1", -1);
    else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Geçtin", "Mesaj -1", -1);


    }


}`
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. What's your question?

Comment: Based on you error, the input is blank because you're creating a new instance of `gui` which has nothing to do with the instance of `gui` which is on the screen and the user is interacting with

Comment: The stack trace associated with the exception will direct you to the exact source line on which the error occurs.  However, the only plausible location I see in the code you've presented is line 11 of Action.java, where you have `int a = Integer.parseInt(b.Text.getText());`.  What do you suppose happens when that line is triggered, and the text field's content is empty or otherwise non-numeric?

Comment: But in guii.java i add setText i mean it give me a inputdialog i write a number and set it to Text and after i click button it should convert it to integer and did its work